# pycharm will not allow me to use my python on an Ubuntu operating system

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I have been working on getting pycharm to use python easy right.. wrong, when I try to add python 3.5 the gui, keeps going back to no SDK at all and it won't let me add one. to better explain the problem I made this video to help. what I am doing should work but it is not. note this is on an Ubuntu operating system.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5dy1jlIHCs

Answer (score 0):

It seems weird beucase JetBrains' product detects local SDK first without *pain*, but you have really problem with that.

Anyway, I think, we can solve the problem.

1. Try to look PyCharm log. You may see interesting things over there.
2. Delete VirtualEnv and use `/usr/bin/python3.5`. (Maybe, it can solve)
3. Check JetBrains owner (`chown`), read and write permissions (`chmod`). Also, check `.idea` file

> NOTE:
>
> This **invalid VCS** doesn't effect your usage of SDK because JetBrains has to read .idea to find your VCS settings (or other things)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have two interpreters with the same name, not sure how it happened but PyCharm doesn't allow it

[image]

remove one, also you select an interpreter for a wrong project (you have multiple opened)

[image]